# Dell Inspiron 15-5547 Shutting Down Immediately After Startup

Tags: laptop, battery, power, dell-inspiron

I am working on servicing a friend's laptop, and I cannot find what the problem is. The reason that I started servicing the laptop was that he was having issues where the laptop would shut down immediately after he presses the power button, as if his battery were coming disconnected. I disassembled the laptop, but nothing seemed broken or disconnected. I did, however, fix the broken hinge in the laptop, which was nice. I already checked that it wasn't the charger, and I made sure that the socket on the laptop had a solid connection. Has anyone else seen a similar problem, or know how to fix this particular issue?

Comment: If you remove the battery, and then plug it into the adapter, does it work then?

Comment: Maybe the battery is bad?

Comment: Tried it without the battery, and it booted just fine. So it was a problem with the battery. Note to self: try that first next time.